# how to create regex for (-) not repeat after 3 digit inside formik setfieldvalue

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native, formik

i have regex function like this:

```
const format = (value) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      return value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d+)/g, '$1-$2');
    }
}
```

when i console without inputing into formik setfieldvalue it produce correct regex like 111-1111111:

```
const custom = (value) => {
   console.log('valuemain',format(value)); //this valuemain: 111-1111111
   formikRef.current.setFieldValue('customnumb',value)
}
```

but when i inputing regex into formik setfieldvalue it becomes like 111-111-111:

```
const custom = (value) => {
   console.log('valuemain',format(value)); //this valuemain: 111-111-111
   formikRef.current.setFieldValue('customnumb',format(value))
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Calling `setFieldValue()` can't change how `format()` works before it's called. Try logging `value` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace beforehand all occurrences of hyphen `"-"` with `""` (*empty string*)

```js
const format = (val = "") => val.replace(/-/g, "").replace(/(\d{3})(\d+)/g, '$1-$2');

console.log(format("1111111111"));        // "111-1111111"
console.log(format("111-1111111"));       // "111-1111111"
console.log(format("111-11-1-1-1-11"));   // "111-1111111"
```

Since obviously **you're only interested in integers**; to be politically more correct, instead of replacing only the hyphens `"-"` you could replace (using RegExp `\D` *Not a Digit*) — everything that is **not a digit**:

```js
const format = (val = "") => {
  // @TODO: do val checks if needed here.
  return val
    .replace(/\D/g, "")                 // Remove everything that is not a digit
    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d+)/g, '$1-$2');  // Format as desired
};

console.log(format("1111111111"));        // "111-1111111"
console.log(format("111-1111111"));       // "111-1111111"
console.log(format("111-11-1-1-1-11"));   // "111-1111111"
```

Comment: Thank you @ImNewBtw Added another example. Hope it helps.